# Signal processing: How to patch over dip in signal using R?

Tags: r, signal-processing

I am a biologist starting to use R to analyze my data.

Could anybody please help me solve my problem I encountered when working in signal processing in R?

**Problem**
I have a recording of a signal in a form of 2 columns (x=row number, y=intensity) with some well defined drops in the signal.

[image: My signal with drops in the signal highlighted by red arrows]

I would like to bridge these drops using a simple line anchored at the manually selected endpoints as shown below.

[image: How it should look in the end:)]

[I can manually get coordinations of the end points (X,Y).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM3Nm.png)

Example data: [exampleData](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rkL9yeOEWb1cP8jNaDWFnanGckfSJ28c/view?usp=sharing)

**My idea of solution:**

I go through the acquisition files, manually collect the start (X1,Y1) and end (X2,Y2) points coordinates for each acquisition, save as .csv file

Have a script which calculates line segments connecting these endpoints in form of two columns ranging from X1toX2 in row numbers, Y1toY2 in intensity.

Have a script replaces that the dip in the original data with the line segment.

**What I do not know:**

How to make a function which based on start ( X1, Y1)and end point (X2, Y2) coordinates generates X2-X1 rows with values from Y1 to Y2.

**Notes:**
I have some 50 files to go through.
There can be more dips in the signal in given acquisition file.

**Example data here:**

```
dput(dataInput[1:2500,])
structure(list(X = 0:2499, Y = c(87, 87.3333, 86.3333, 85.6667, 
85.3333, 86, 85, 84.6667, 85, 84, 83.6667, 83, 82, 82, 82.3333, 
81.6667, 82.3333, 81.3333, 80.6667, 79.6667, 80.3333, 79.3333, 
79, 79, 78.3333, 78.6667, 77.6667, 78, 77.3333, 78, 76.6667, 
77, 76.3333, 75.6667, 75.3333, 74.6667, 75.6667, 74.3333, 73.6667, 
74.3333, 74, 73.6667, 74.3333, 72.6667, 72.6667, 72.3333, 73, 
72, 72.6667, 71.6667, 71, 71.3333, 71.6667, 70.6667, 70, 70.6667, 
70.6667, 69.6667, 69.6667, 69, 68.6667, 68, 69, 68.6667, 68, 
68, 66.6667, 67, 67.3333, 66.3333, 67, 66.3333, 66.3333, 66.6667, 
66, 65.6667, 66, 65.3333, 65.6667, 64.6667, 65, 64.6667, 64.3333, 
63.6667, 63.6667, 64, 64, 63.3333, 63, 63.3333, 62.6667, 62.6667, 
62.3333, 62, 62.6667, 62, 61.3333, 61.3333, 61.3333, 61, 61, 
61.6667, 61.3333, 61.6667, 60.6667, 60.6667, 60, 59.6667, 59.6667, 
59.3333, 59.6667, 59.3333, 60, 58.3333, 58.6667, 58.3333, 59.3333, 
59, 58, 58, 58, 57, 58.3333, 58.3333, 58, 57.3333, 57.3333, 57.3333, 
58, 56.6667, 57, 56.6667, 56, 56.6667, 56, 56.6667, 56.6667, 
56, 55.6667, 56, 55.6667, 54.3333, 55.3333, 55, 54.6667, 55.3333, 
54.6667, 55, 54, 54.6667, 54.3333, 54.3333, 54.6667, 54, 54.3333, 
53.6667, 54, 54, 52.6667, 53.6667, 53.3333, 53, 53.3333, 52.6667, 
53, 53, 52.6667, 52, 52.3333, 52.3333, 52, 52.3333, 52, 52, 51.6667, 
51.6667, 52, 51.3333, 50.3333, 50.3333, 52, 51.3333, 51.3333, 
51, 50.6667, 51.3333, 51, 50, 51, 50.6667, 51, 50.6667, 50.6667, 
50.6667, 50.6667, 50.3333, 50.3333, 51, 49.6667, 50.6667, 49.6667, 
49.3333, 49.6667, 49.3333, 49, 49.6667, 49.3333, 49.3333, 48.6667, 
48.6667, 48.6667, 48.6667, 48.6667, 48, 48, 48.3333, 49, 48.3333, 
49, 48.3333, 48, 47.3333, 48, 48.3333, 47.6667, 47.6667, 47.6667, 
48, 47.6667, 47.3333, 47.6667, 48, 47.6667, 47.3333, 46.3333, 
47.3333, 47, 46.6667, 46.6667, 46.3333, 47, 46.6667, 46, 46, 
46.6667, 47, 46.6667, 46.3333, 45.6667, 46.3333, 45.6667, 45.3333, 
46, 46, 45.6667, 46.3333, 45.6667, 45.6667, 46.3333, 45, 45.6667, 
45.6667, 45, 45.3333, 45.6667, 45.3333, 45.3333, 45, 44.6667, 
45.6667, 44.6667, 45.3333, 44.3333, 45, 45, 45.3333, 45.3333, 
44.6667, 44.6667, 44.6667, 45.3333, 44.6667, 44.3333, 43.6667, 
44.3333, 44, 44.3333, 45, 43.6667, 44, 43.6667, 44, 44, 43, 43.6667, 
43.3333, 44, 44.3333, 43.6667, 43.3333, 43.6667, 43.3333, 44.3333, 
43.3333, 43.3333, 43, 43.3333, 44, 42.6667, 43.3333, 43.6667, 
43, 43, 44, 42.6667, 43.6667, 43.3333, 42.6667, 43, 42, 41.6667, 
42.6667, 42.6667, 42.6667, 42, 43, 41.6667, 42.3333, 42, 41.6667, 
41.6667, 41.6667, 41.3333, 42, 41.6667, 42, 42, 41.6667, 42, 
42, 42, 41.3333, 41.6667, 42, 42, 41.3333, 41.6667, 41.6667, 
41.3333, 40.6667, 41, 40.6667, 41, 41.3333, 41.6667, 41, 41.6667, 
40.3333, 40.3333, 41.3333, 40, 41.3333, 40.3333, 41.3333, 40, 
41.6667, 41.3333, 40.6667, 40.6667, 41, 40, 40, 40.6667, 40.3333, 
41, 40.3333, 40.6667, 40.3333, 40.3333, 40, 40.6667, 40, 40.6667, 
40, 40, 40.3333, 40, 40, 40, 40.3333, 39.6667, 39.6667, 39.6667, 
40, 40, 40.6667, 40.3333, 40.6667, 39.6667, 40.3333, 39, 40, 
40, 39.6667, 39.6667, 39.3333, 39.3333, 39.6667, 39.6667, 39.6667, 
39.6667, 39, 39.6667, 39.6667, 39.3333, 39.3333, 40, 39.6667, 
39.6667, 38.6667, 39.3333, 39.6667, 39, 38.6667, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39.3333, 39.3333, 39, 37.6667, 38.6667, 39, 39.3333, 39.3333, 
39, 38.6667, 38.6667, 38.6667, 39, 38.3333, 39, 38.3333, 37.6667, 
38, 39, 38.3333, 39, 38.3333, 38, 38, 38.6667, 38.3333, 39, 38, 
38.3333, 38.3333, 38, 38.3333, 38, 38, 37.6667, 39.3333, 38.3333, 
38.3333, 37.6667, 37.6667, 38, 37.3333, 37.6667, 37.6667, 37.6667, 
38, 38, 38, 37.6667, 38, 38, 37.6667, 38, 37.3333, 37.3333, 37.3333, 
37.3333, 37.3333, 37, 37, 37.6667, 37, 37.3333, 37.3333, 37.6667, 
37, 37.6667, 37.6667, 37, 37, 37.3333, 37, 37.3333, 37, 36.6667, 
37, 37, 37, 37.6667, 37.3333, 36.3333, 37.3333, 36.3333, 36.6667, 
37, 37, 36.6667, 36.6667, 37, 36.6667, 37.3333, 36.3333, 36, 
36.6667, 37, 36.3333, 36.3333, 37, 36.6667, 36.3333, 36.6667, 
36.6667, 37, 37, 37, 36.6667, 36, 36.3333, 36.6667, 36.3333, 
36.6667, 36.3333, 36.6667, 36.6667, 36, 36.3333, 36.3333, 36.6667, 
36, 36.3333, 36, 36, 36.3333, 36, 36, 37, 36.6667, 36.3333, 36, 
36, 36, 35.3333, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.6667, 36.3333, 
36.3333, 36, 35.6667, 35.6667, 36, 35.6667, 36, 35.6667, 36, 
35.3333, 35.3333, 36, 35.3333, 35.6667, 36, 35.6667, 35.6667, 
35.3333, 36, 36, 35.3333, 35, 36, 35.6667, 35.3333, 35.3333, 
35, 35.6667, 35.3333, 35, 36, 36, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.3333, 
36.3333, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.3333, 35.3333, 35, 35.6667, 35, 
35.3333, 35.3333, 34.6667, 35, 35.3333, 35.6667, 35, 35.6667, 
35.3333, 35, 35, 35, 35.3333, 34.3333, 35, 35, 35.3333, 35, 35.3333, 
35, 35.6667, 35, 35, 34.6667, 35, 35.3333, 35, 35, 35, 34.3333, 
34.6667, 35, 35, 35.3333, 35, 35.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 35, 
35, 34.6667, 34.6667, 34.6667, 35.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.6667, 
34.6667, 34, 28.3333, 28, 28.6667, 28, 28, 28, 27.6667, 28, 27.6667, 
28.3333, 27.6667, 26.6667, 26, 25.3333, 25.3333, 25.6667, 25, 
25.3333, 25, 25, 25.3333, 25, 24.6667, 25.6667, 25, 25, 25.3333, 
24.6667, 24.6667, 24.3333, 25, 25, 25, 25, 24.6667, 25.6667, 
25, 25, 25, 25.6667, 25, 24, 24.6667, 25, 24.6667, 25, 24.6667, 
25.3333, 25.6667, 25, 25.3333, 24, 25, 24.3333, 25, 25, 25, 24.3333, 
24.6667, 24.6667, 25, 24.3333, 24.6667, 24.6667, 24, 24.3333, 
24.3333, 24.6667, 24, 24.3333, 24, 24.6667, 25, 25, 24.6667, 
24, 27.6667, 30.3333, 30.3333, 30, 30.3333, 30.3333, 30.6667, 
31.3333, 31.3333, 31, 31, 30.6667, 30.6667, 31, 31, 30.3333, 
30, 31.6667, 30.3333, 31.6667, 31.3333, 30.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 
30.6667, 31.3333, 30.6667, 31.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 31.3333, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.3333, 31.6667, 31.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.3333, 32.6667, 31.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 33, 
32, 32, 33, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 33.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 33, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.3333, 
32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 
31.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
32, 32, 32.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.3333, 33.3333, 
32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 33, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 31.3333, 32.3333, 32, 
32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 33, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 33, 32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32, 31.6667, 
32.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 33, 32.6667, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32.6667, 33, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 31.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32, 31.3333, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 32, 31.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 33, 31.3333, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 31.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 
31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 
32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 33, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
32.6667, 31.6667, 33.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 32, 32, 31.6667, 32, 33, 31.6667, 32.3333, 33, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 31.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 31.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 
32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 31.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 33, 32, 32.3333, 
32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 32.6667, 32.6667, 33, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 
32.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 33, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32.6667, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 33, 32.3333, 31.6667, 
27.6667, 27.3333, 26.6667, 26, 26.3333, 26.3333, 26, 26.3333, 
26.3333, 26, 26.3333, 25.3333, 24.6667, 24, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
24, 23.6667, 24, 24, 24, 23.6667, 23.6667, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24.3333, 24, 24, 23.6667, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
24, 23.3333, 24, 24, 24.3333, 23.6667, 23.3333, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
23.6667, 24, 24.3333, 24, 23.6667, 23.3333, 24, 23.6667, 24, 
24, 24, 23.3333, 23.3333, 23.3333, 23.3333, 23.6667, 24, 23.6667, 
24, 23.6667, 24, 24, 23.6667, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 23.6667, 23.6667, 
24, 25, 29, 29.3333, 29, 29, 29, 29.6667, 29.6667, 30, 30, 29.6667, 
29.6667, 30, 29.6667, 29.6667, 30, 30.3333, 30, 29.6667, 29.6667, 
29.6667, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30.3333, 29.6667, 29.6667, 30, 31, 31, 
31.3333, 30.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31, 31.3333, 29.6667, 31, 
30.6667, 31.6667, 30.6667, 31, 31, 31.3333, 30.3333, 30.6667, 
31.3333, 31, 31.6667, 30.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.6667, 
30.6667, 31.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.3333, 
31, 31, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.3333, 31, 30.6667, 31.3333, 
30.6667, 31.3333, 31.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 30.6667, 31, 31.6667, 
31.3333, 32, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
31.3333, 31.3333, 32.3333, 31.6667, 31.6667, 32, 31.6667, 31.6667, 
32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 31.3333, 
31.6667, 32, 31.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 32.6667, 32, 32.3333, 
32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32, 31.6667, 32, 32, 32.6667, 
32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 31.6667, 31.3333, 
31.6667, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
32.6667, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31.6667, 32.3333, 32.3333, 32.3333, 
31.6667, 33, 32.3333, 32, 32, 32.3333, 31.3333, 33, 33, 32.6667, 
32.3333, 32, 33, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.6667, 33, 32.6667, 
33.6667, 32.6667, 33, 32.6667, 32.6667, 33.3333, 33, 33.3333, 
33.6667, 33, 32.6667, 33, 33.3333, 33, 33.3333, 33.6667, 33.3333, 
33, 33, 34.3333, 33.3333, 33.6667, 33.6667, 33, 33.6667, 33.6667, 
33.6667, 33.6667, 34.3333, 34, 34, 34.3333, 33.6667, 33.6667, 
34.3333, 34, 34, 34.3333, 34.3333, 35, 34, 33.6667, 35, 34.3333, 
34.3333, 34.6667, 34.6667, 35.6667, 34.6667, 35, 35.3333, 35, 
35.6667, 34.6667, 35.6667, 35.6667, 36, 35.6667, 36.6667, 36, 
36, 37, 37.6667, 39, 40.3333, 43.3333, 47.6667, 52, 53.3333, 
55.6667, 57.6667, 58, 58.6667, 60.6667, 61, 61.6667, 62, 61.6667, 
62.6667, 62.6667, 63.3333, 63, 64, 64.6667, 64.3333, 64.3333, 
65, 65.3333, 65, 66, 66.6667, 66, 67, 67, 67.3333, 68.3333, 67.3333, 
67.6667, 68.3333, 67.6667, 68.3333, 68.3333, 68.3333, 69, 68.6667, 
68.6667, 69.6667, 69.3333, 70, 69.6667, 70.3333, 71, 71.3333, 
70.6667, 72, 72, 72.3333, 71.6667, 71.3333, 72, 72.3333, 72.6667, 
72, 72.6667, 74, 74.3333, 74, 74, 74.3333, 74.3333, 74.3333, 
74, 74.6667, 74, 75.3333, 74.3333, 75.6667, 74.6667, 75.3333, 
75, 75.6667, 76, 75.6667, 75.3333, 76.6667, 76.6667, 77.3333, 
76.3333, 76.3333, 77, 77.6667, 77.6667, 76.6667, 78, 77.6667, 
78.6667, 78.3333, 77.3333, 78.3333, 77.6667, 78.6667, 79, 78.3333, 
79, 79, 79.3333, 79, 79.3333, 78.6667, 79.3333, 79.6667, 79.3333, 
80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 80.3333, 80, 80.3333, 80.6667, 79.6667, 80, 
80.6667, 81.6667, 81, 80.3333, 81, 81.6667, 82, 81.3333, 82, 
82.3333, 81.3333, 81.3333, 82, 81.6667, 82, 81.6667, 83.3333, 
83, 82, 82.3333, 83.3333, 83.3333, 83.3333, 83.3333, 83, 83, 
84.3333, 83.3333, 83.6667, 83.3333, 83, 83.6667, 84, 84.3333, 
84.3333, 84, 84, 84, 82.6667, 84.6667, 84.6667, 85, 85, 84.6667, 
84.3333, 84.6667, 85.3333, 84.3333, 85.3333, 85.3333, 85.3333, 
85, 84.6667, 85.6667, 86.3333, 85.3333, 86.3333, 86, 85.3333, 
85.3333, 86, 85.3333, 86, 87, 86.6667, 85.3333, 86.6667, 87, 
86, 86.6667, 87.3333, 87, 87.6667, 86.6667, 86.3333, 86.3333, 
87.3333, 87, 88, 86.6667, 87.6667, 87.3333, 87.6667, 88, 87.3333, 
87.3333, 87.3333, 87.6667, 88, 88, 87.6667, 88.3333, 87.6667, 
87.6667, 87, 88, 87.6667, 87.3333, 88, 87.3333, 87.6667, 88.3333, 
88.3333, 88, 88, 87.3333, 88.3333, 88.6667, 88.3333, 88.3333, 
88, 89.3333, 89.3333, 89, 88.6667, 88.6667, 88, 89, 88.6667, 
89.6667, 89.3333, 89, 89.3333, 89.6667, 88.6667, 88.3333, 89, 
89, 89.3333, 89.6667, 89.6667, 89.3333, 89.3333, 88.6667, 89, 
88.3333, 90, 88.3333, 90.3333, 89, 89.6667, 90, 89.3333, 89, 
89.6667, 88.6667, 89, 88.6667, 89.6667, 89.3333, 88.6667, 88.6667, 
88.6667, 88, 88, 87, 87.6667, 87, 86.6667, 86.6667, 86.3333, 
86, 85.6667, 85.3333, 84.3333, 83.6667, 84, 83, 82.6667, 82.6667, 
82.6667, 82, 82.3333, 81.6667, 80.6667, 80, 80.3333, 80, 79.3333, 
78.6667, 79, 78, 78, 78, 77, 77, 76.3333, 75.6667, 77, 75.6667, 
74.6667, 75.3333, 75, 74.3333, 73.3333, 73.6667, 73, 72.3333, 
72.3333, 72.6667, 72.3333, 71.6667, 71, 70.3333, 71.3333, 71, 
69.6667, 70, 69.3333, 69.3333, 69, 68.3333, 68.6667, 68.3333, 
68, 67.6667, 67.3333, 67.6667, 67, 66.6667, 67, 67, 66, 65.6667, 
66, 65.3333, 65.3333, 64.6667, 64.6667, 64.6667, 63.3333, 64, 
64.6667, 64, 64, 63.3333, 62, 63, 63, 62, 61.6667, 61.6667, 62, 
61.6667, 60.3333, 61, 61.3333, 60, 60.6667, 59.3333, 59.6667, 
60, 59.6667, 59.6667, 59.3333, 59.3333, 59.3333, 58.6667, 58, 
58.3333, 57.6667, 58, 58, 57.3333, 57, 57.3333, 57, 57, 56.3333, 
56.3333, 56.6667, 56, 57, 57, 55.3333, 55, 56.3333, 55.3333, 
55.6667, 55.3333, 55.3333, 55.3333, 55, 54, 54.6667, 54, 54, 
54.6667, 53.6667, 54, 54, 54, 53, 53, 53, 53, 52.3333, 53, 52.3333, 
52.3333, 52, 52.6667, 52.3333, 51, 51.6667, 51.6667, 52, 51.3333, 
51.3333, 51, 51, 50.6667, 50.6667, 50.6667, 50.6667, 50.3333, 
50.6667, 50.6667, 50, 50.3333, 50, 50.6667, 50, 50, 49.3333, 
49, 49.3333, 49.3333, 49, 48.6667, 49, 49.3333, 48.6667, 48.3333, 
48.3333, 49, 49, 49, 48.6667, 48.3333, 48.3333, 48, 48, 47.3333, 
48, 48, 47, 47, 48, 47.6667, 46.6667, 46.6667, 47.6667, 47.3333, 
47, 46.6667, 47.3333, 47, 46.3333, 46, 46, 46, 46.3333, 46.3333, 
46, 46, 45.6667, 46, 46.3333, 46, 45.3333, 45.6667, 45.6667, 
45.6667, 44.6667, 45.3333, 45.6667, 45.3333, 45.3333, 44.6667, 
45, 45, 44.6667, 44.6667, 45, 44.6667, 44.3333, 44, 44.3333, 
44.3333, 43.3333, 44.3333, 44, 43.6667, 44, 44, 43.6667, 43.6667, 
44, 43.3333, 43.6667, 43.6667, 43.6667, 43.3333, 43, 42.6667, 
43.3333, 43.3333, 43.3333, 43, 43.3333, 42.3333, 43, 42.6667, 
42.3333, 43, 42.6667, 43, 42.3333, 42.3333, 42.3333, 42.3333, 
42.6667, 42.6667, 42.3333, 42.3333, 42.3333, 41.6667, 41.6667, 
42, 41.6667, 41.6667, 42.6667, 41.6667, 41, 41.3333, 42, 41.6667, 
42, 42, 41.6667, 41.3333, 41.6667, 41.3333, 41, 35.6667, 33.6667, 
33.6667, 32.6667, 33.3333, 32.3333, 32.6667, 32.6667, 32.3333, 
32, 32.6667, 31.6667, 30, 29.6667, 30, 29.3333, 29.6667, 29.6667, 
29.3333, 28.3333, 28.6667, 29.6667, 29.6667, 28.6667, 29, 28.6667, 
29.3333, 29, 28.3333, 29, 28.6667, 29, 28.3333, 29.3333, 28.6667, 
28.3333, 29, 28, 28.3333, 29, 28.3333, 28, 28.6667, 28.3333, 
28.3333, 28.6667, 28, 28, 28, 27.6667, 28, 28, 28, 28.3333, 28.3333, 
28, 28, 28.3333, 28, 27.6667, 28, 27.6667, 27.6667, 27.6667, 
27.6667, 27.3333, 28, 27.3333, 27.6667, 27.6667, 27.3333, 27.6667, 
27.3333, 28, 27.6667, 27.6667, 32.3333, 33.6667, 33.6667, 34.3333, 
33.6667, 33.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.6667, 34, 34.6667, 34.3333, 
34.3333, 34.3333, 34, 34.6667, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34, 
34.3333, 34, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.6667, 34.3333, 
35, 35.3333, 35.3333, 36, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35.3333, 
35.6667, 35.3333, 35, 35, 35.6667, 35.6667, 35, 35, 35.6667, 
35.3333, 35, 35, 35.3333, 34.6667, 35.3333, 35, 35.6667, 35.3333, 
34.6667, 35, 34.3333, 35.3333, 35, 34.6667, 34.6667, 35.6667, 
35.3333, 34.3333, 35, 34.6667, 35, 34.3333, 34.6667, 34.3333, 
34.3333, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.6667, 35, 35, 
34.6667, 34.6667, 34.3333, 34.3333, 35, 34.6667, 35, 34.6667, 
34, 35, 34.6667, 34, 34.6667, 34.6667, 34, 34.6667, 34.6667, 
35, 34, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34, 34.3333, 35, 34.3333, 34.6667, 
34.3333, 34, 34.6667, 33.6667, 34, 34.3333, 34, 35, 35, 34.6667, 
34, 33.6667, 35, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34.3333, 34, 34.3333, 34.3333, 
34, 34, 33.6667, 34.3333, 34.3333, 33.3333, 34.3333, 34, 34.3333, 
34.3333, 34, 34, 34, 34, 33.6667, 34.6667, 34, 34, 33.6667, 34.6667, 
34, 33.6667)), row.names = c(NA, 2500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your solution of "bridging the line" does not appear to be well-defined. For instance, applying it to your data (the first 2500 points) would cause you to extend a horizontal line from (655, 34.6667) all the way to (1697, 34.6667), thereby obliterating an extended portion of your signal that spans *two* drop outs. Is that really what you want? Although many solutions are possible that will work for the example data, it would be better to develop them based on some understanding of what this signal means and what causes the drop-outs: that would assure their applicability in the other 49 cases.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for your comment. 
I need to bridge over these gaps in order to feed it into another peak detecting programme (clampfit) which I use to define width of the peak, its height, and some more parameters. However these dips in the signal does not allow the following programme to process it. The dips in the signal were caused by malfunctioning mirror in our microscope, which was later fixed,but I would still like to squeeze results even from these imperfect data.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your attention, I guess I did not describe it clearly.
I need to span each drop out with a line, not necessarily horizontal line, so in the case of the first arrow would go from 1400 to cca 1600 in X axis, would be horizontal in this case, but not in each, the endpoints would be selected manually. Hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: Since the selection is manual, would it be fair to say your question concerns only *detecting* the signal dropouts?

Comment: Dear whuber while it would be nice to have the detection automated, it is not what I am after. I would be sufficiently happy with detecting and recording the start and end points of the dropouts manually and just patch over the dips automatically based on them. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Although it is difficult to determine general behavior from one dataset, it looks like **these data would be amenable to a simple, robust analysis that looks for sudden drops followed a little later by a sudden rise.**  (I adopt the language of time series analysis in which row numbers are viewed as succeeding points in time.)

**To find a drop, predict the data in a robust way.**  A moving (windowed) median will do nicely, perhaps of width 5 through 50.  Sufficiently large negative discrepancies between actual and predicted values (the "residuals") will indicate drops.  The rises can be discovered by reversing the series and looking for its drops, obviating any need to code two algorithms.

**The main challenge to automating this lies in estimating how large a "sufficiently large" drop must be.**  In this case, because the signal is discrete (all values are multiplies of 1/3), a tabulation of the residuals reveals a few extreme values that appear only a few times: those are the candidates for further examination.

**These candidates must be post-processed** to combine quick successions of drops into the first drop in each sequence and to eliminate the "false" drops and rises created by rapid decreases or increases (respectively) in the valid part of the signal.

**Here is a plot of the data** with the drops marked in red, the rises in blue, and the data in between each such pair (corresponding to the invalid signal) in gray.  No tuning or manual intervention was performed.  The window width was 41 rows, but any window larger than 4 yet smaller than the durations of the bad signals will work fine *with this dataset.*  Whether this approach works with your other datasets will depend on whether I have guessed correctly at the nature of the signal dropouts.

[image: Figure 1]

For further details, consult this `R` code used to produce the figure.  It references the data as a data frame `X` having fields `X` and `Y`.  It adds a third field `Y.hat` equal to the good data and otherwise containing `NA` (missing) values for the signal dropouts it detected.

```
#
# Plot the data.
#
with(X, plot(X, Y, type="l", ylim=c(0,100), bty="n", col="#00000040", xlab="X", ylab="Y", 
             main="Data and Gaps"))
#
# Find the sudden drops in both directions.
#
drops <- function(x, w=1) {
  require(zoo)
  #
  # Smooth the differences.
  #
  dx <- c(0, diff(x))
  r <- rollapply(dx, 2*w+1, median, align="right", fill=NA)
  #
  # Identify the extreme differences.
  #
  counts <- table(r <- round(r - dx, ceiling(-log10(range(x)))+2))
  i <- as.numeric(names(table(counts)))
  u <- min(which(diff(i) > 1))
  thresholds <- as.numeric(names(counts)[counts < u])
  upper <- min(thresholds[thresholds > 0])
  #
  # Return the indexes where those extreme drops occur.
  #
  which(r >= upper)
}

w <- 20 # Specify the half-window size.
i <- drops(X$Y, w)
j <- rev(nrow(X)+1 - drops(rev(X$Y), w))
#
# Look for drop/rise pairs.
#
if (min(j) < min(i)) i <- c(1,i)
if (max(i) > max(j)) j <- c(j, nrow(X))
ij <- sort(c(i,j))

inds <- c(rep(0, length(i)), rep(1, length(j)))[order(c(i,j))]
i.drops <- ij[which(c(inds,1)==0 & c(1,inds)==1)] # First 0-->1
i.rises <- ij[which(c(inds,1)==1 & c(1,inds)==0)] # Last 0-->1

abline(v=X$X[i.drops], col="Red")
abline(v=X$X[i.rises], col="Blue")
#
# Remove the intervals between drop/rise pairs from the data and plot them in gray.
#
X$Y.hat <- X$Y
for (k in seq_along(i.drops))
  X$Y.hat[i.drops[k]:i.rises[k]] <- NA

lines(X$X, X$Y.hat)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you whuber, looks very useful. I will try to apply to my dataset and see how it works. Thanks very much:)